# Register a script to use with the rails command, like `rails mycommand`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The `rails` command-line command provides a couple of commands, like `rails generate`, `rails console` etc. Now I'd like write a gem which registers my own command for use with `rails mycommand`.

Is this possible?
If so, any guides on how to do that?

NB: This is for rails 3+

regards, apeiros

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done it, but here are some leads. In your Rails app, the script directory holds a file called 'rails' that has this line

```
 # This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.
```

It then requires this Rails file:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb